# error al importar un archivo en python

Tags: python, python-import

se me presenta el siguiente error al importar un archivo en python
error `SyntaxError: invalid syntaxjedi` alguien sabe que procede ?

```
from 'src/test/agi' import recived_data
```

así lo estoy haciendo

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Es que la forma en la que lo estás importando no es valida.

Si lo que quieres es importar un módulo de un subdirectorio, todas las carpetas que hay en el directorio deben tener un formato valido (solo letras, numeros o guion bajo) y no ser solo numero.

Si tu directorio cumple estos requisitos, puedes hacer el import así usando el punto como si fuera la barra:

```
from src.test.agi import recived_data
```

Si buscas más flexibilidad al importar modulos, te recomiendo ver el modulo [importlib](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/importlib.html). Es parte de la librería estandar, por lo que no es necesario instalar nada.
Sin embargo, te recomiendo usar la forma convencional siempre que sea posible.

Lectura recomendada: https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: entiendo, pero si estoy el modulo que necesito importar esta en un directorio de un nivel mas alto a donde esta el modulo actual por medio de puntos como podría acceder?

Comment: Te refieres a si por ejemplo tienes un programa en "c:/prueba" y quieres acceder a un modulo en "c:/prueba/lib"?

Comment: tengo a client en un directorio que esta dos niveles mas arriab de donde esta el modulo desde donde quiero acceder. esto no me deja colocar la imagen de los nivles de los archivos

Comment: Cuando dices "dos niveles más arriba" te refieres por ejemplo a que el programa está en c:/test/prog y el modulo en c:/?